# Deserialize JSON for a class I dont own with custom getters

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, jackson-databind

I am trying to deserialize an object of a class that I do not own. The class has attribute names such as `id_`, `address_`, `name_`, but its getters are `getId()` `getAddress()` `getName`() etc.

When I try to deserialize the JSON using Jackson, I get

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "id_", not marked as ignorable
```

It looks like this happens because Jackson's looking for `getId_()` instead of `getId()`. Since I do not own the underlying class, I cannot use Jackson's annotations to map attributes to custom json fields.

How can I deserialize with a custom mapping of object attributes to its getter methods?

Comment: Perhaps try Jackson's JsonNode: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-jsonnode.html

Comment: Not really a perfect solution, but you can just create your own class, deserialise to that class and have it have a `toOriginalClass()` method.

Comment: How does your JSON input look like?
Is it `{"id":123, "name":"John Doe"}` or ìs it `{"id_":123, "name_":"John Doe"}`?

Comment: @ThomasFritsch The latter. JSON looks like `{"id_":123, "name_":"John Doe"}`

Comment: @korolar, Looking to avoid that as possible. Since we do not own the original class, I dont want to be coupled to any changes the owners might make

Answer (score 1):

You can try a custom deserializer.

check out: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

This way you can register a deserializer for the class.

However, you still have to edit it when the class changes.

One other thing you can try:

```
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
```

This will give the mapper full access to private members.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a **MixIn** for Jackson - that's how I solved my issue trying to serialize and deserialize JSON for an auto-generated AVRO class ([Avro generated class issue with json conversion [kotlin]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56742226/avro-generated-class-issue-with-json-conversion-kotlin))

Here is an example:

https://medium.com/@shankar.ganesh.1234/jackson-mixin-a-simple-guide-to-a-powerful-feature-d984341dc9e2