# Is there a way to generate @jsonignore annotation for schema generated via avro?

Tags: json, object, properties, avro, transient

Suppose I generate a domain object with several properties.I want to generate @jsonignore annotation for one of the object properties in the class defn.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can directly add an additional annotation, but you can add a MixIn to your ObjectMapper.

See this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56749899/1115279